# Retrieving JSON data from WordPress mysql database to android studio directly

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress e-commerce project that need to be converted into a mobile App.

I created few custom PHP files besides regular WP files where using PHP codes I'm sending products data by JSON directly from MySQL WP database. 
But I'm facing two problems here:

1) If there are more than 20 posts/products in a wp_posts table then JSON page becomes empty but if they are less than 20 then the data are passing properly.

2) I think the process is not secure because the URL which contains JSON data are publicly accessable so anyone who knows the URL of JSON page will get access all secret data like username and password.

Question 1: Is there any other way to send data from MySQL to Android except JSON, also way to restrict access to JSON URL page publicly?

Question 2: Because this is an e-commerce website so there will be more than 20k+ posts/products, so will a single JSON page be able to handle those 20k+ data? 20+ data is turning the page black currently, so how to solve those issues? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Is there any other way to send data from MySQL to Android except JSON` that's not the question you want to ask. Correct question is why does it fail to send when you ask for more than 20 items. `way to restrict access to JSON URL page publicly` there is a tone of ways. Just use search.

Comment: A quick suggestion to get answers to your question on stack...  First, keep in mind that your site is a wordpress site.  So, assuming you want to use that tool to feed data to your android app, all of your questions are related to wordpress.  How do you make a wordpress url secure? How do you get more than 20 items to be included in Wordpress? How do I supply user name/password to wordpress using the android api? etc.

Comment: Next comment:  this question is one that most stack users wont tackle.  Tha's because you're actually asking 3 or 4 questions at once.  It's really hard to answers all of these questions in 1 post!  Most stack members have time to answer just ONE of your questions at any given moment.  I'd suggest breaking out your work into phases:  (1) get to know how to restrict a wordpress url to ONLY one user.  (2) figure out how to call that page from android and get it to return content.  Then, (3) return json, and ask your json-specific questions above (returning 20+ vs < 20).  Hope all that's helpful!